# Problem with C# submitting file to IBM MQ Broker

Tags: c#, websphere, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I am trying to submit a Soap XML payload file to our IBM MQ Broker, which will then pass the file on to the destination application. I don't have direct connectivity to the destination app, so I'm forced to go through the Broker.
I've never worked with the Broker before, and I can't find anyone here who knows anything about it. Previous code from a previous application (that we are no longer using) was able to submit files, so I know the Broker works. That's unfortunately the extent of my knowledge of the Broker's inner workings. Any help you can provide would be most appreciated.

The error the Broker is returning is "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'requestUriString')". I don't have this parameter name in my code, and I'm already passing the valid URL value in the code, so I'm not sure what this parameter is, what it's used for exactly, and how/where I can implement it in my code.

We were able to get some code for the Broker decompiled from the other application, but that's all I've got. Here is what I'm working with:

```
string str = fileInfo.FullName;
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(str);
            
HttpWebRequest length = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BrokerService.m_strBrokerURL);
            
xmlReader.MoveToContent();
string str1 = XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader).ToString();
xmlReader.Close();
byte[] bytes = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(str1);
string empty = string.Empty;

length.Method = "POST";
length.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
length.ContentLength = (long)(checked((int)bytes.Length));
            
Stream requestStream = length.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, checked((int)bytes.Length));
requestStream.Close();
            
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)length.GetResponse();
soapResponse = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell...what is BrokerService?

Comment: BrokerService is the class that this code is in